# Cuál es el cálculo exacto para sacar 60 segundos del 100% (PROGRESS BAR)

Tags: javascript, ionic, progressbar, angular5, component

Pregunta principal: ¿Es posible hacerlo como lo estoy estructurando?

Hola muy buenas tengo la duda de cual es el calculo exacto para ir quitandole a un 100% en el que voy mostrando en la parte del progress bar.. que ese tamaño se valla mostrando al width de la barra de progreso disminuyendo ya que quiero que sean una cuenta de retroceso de 60 segundos.

Por ejemplo yo tengo hecho que si 100% lo divides entre 60 me da 1.66
Entonces con un set interval cada segundo le voy restando 1.66 a ese 100%.
Este seria el que se va mostrando al cliente el tamaño de la barra disminuyendo pero internamente es enrrealidad de 60 segundos por lo que tengo otro setinteval ue empieza en 60 y que cada segundo se resta 1.

Esto lo hace bien pero lo de quitarle 1.66 al 100% cada segundo es lo que tengo duda, quiero que se haga exacto los 60 segundos exactos y no sé por cuanto tengo que ir restando.

Gracias de antemano.

```
        <div class="progress-outer">
          <div class="progress-inner" [style.width]="progress + '%'">
            {{loadProgressTime}} s
          </div>
        </div>
```

Este es el del 100% para que se valla mostrando la barra disminuyendo.

```
            var intervalo = setInterval(() => {
              if (this.loadProgress <= 100) {
                this.loadProgress -= 1.6;
              }
              if (this.loadProgress <= 0) {
                alert("se ha terminado");
                clearInterval(intervalo);
              }
            }, 1000);
```

este seria lo de los segundos

```
       var intervalo2 = setInterval(() => {
          if (this.loadProgressTime <= 100) {
            this.loadProgressTime -= 1;

          }

          if (this.loadProgressTime <= 0) {
            alert("se ha terminado");
            clearInterval(intervalo2);
          }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Para ser mas exacto podes restarle 1,6666666667, pero no cambiaria en casi nada a como lo tienes, solo on 0.4